# How to paginate by category and go to a specific record?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I'm very new to mysql and php. I have a product gallery which I manage to put together and copy somebody else code to paginate through the records. The gallery have two tables; one holds the data such as: productID, title, online,...and productTypeID which is a relational field from productType. Now I would like when I click on an image to pass the two parameters productID and productTypeID and create a pagination in the detail page which groups all records by productTypeID but go to a specific record equal to the productID that was passed on the parameter.

I manage to do the pagination query by productTypeID but it will only go to the first record on the array. Here is my code please help.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];

$query_productCount= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productID ='$id'";
$productCount= mysql_query($query_recipeMenu, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_productCount= mysql_fetch_assoc($productCount);
}

if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
  $cat = $_GET['cat'];
}
//check for a page number. If not, set it to page 1


if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))){
    $pagenum = 1;
}else{
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}

//query for record count to setup pagination
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productTypeID='$cat'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($data);


//number of record per page
$page_rows = 1;

//get the last page number
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

//make sure the page number isn't below one, or more than last page num
if ($pagenum < 1){
    $pagenum = 1;
}elseif ($pagenum > $last){
    $pagenum = $last;
}

//Set the range to display in query
$max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

//get all of the record
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productTypeID='$cat' $max");
//check for record
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $productID = $id;
            $productName = $row["productName"];
            $largeImage = $row["largeImage"];
            $productDescription = $row["productDescription"];

            $dynamicList .= ' 
                            <div>
                                <h3>'.$productName.'</h3>
                                <div><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"><img src="images/productImages/'.$largeImage.'" alt="'.$productName.'" width="" /></a></div>

                                <p">'.strip_tags(nl2br($productDescription), "<b><br><p><a>").'</p>




                            </div>

                            ';
    }
}else{
    $dynamicList = "<p>Sorry there are no products under this category</p>";
}
```

Comment: tip: you'd be better off doing a `select count(*) ...` to get the total record number. doing `select *` and then a num_rows() forces the database to start retrieving data from disk that you're only going to be throwing away

Answer (score 0):

You are setting

```
  $page_rows = 1;
```

then

```
//get the last page number
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
```

which would make each page have only one row,

if $rows =30 
 then $last would be ceil(30/1) = 30 and each page has only one row

set $page_rows to number of records you want to display per page.

Update

and set offset values

```
$offset=($page_num-1) * $page_rows;
$max = 'limit ' . $offset .',' .$page_rows;
```

Comment: Im paging by category, I already have a page which display all the record regardless of the category. What I want to accomplish is to paginate on the detail page all record which match the same category...This is done the class is grouping and paging all record but I want it to go to a specific record which would be the same ID as the record which I passed through the parameter id.